# How to check presence of an element in C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I am a bit stuck as to how to write some code that will check if any positions in a 2D array contain a certain variable.

So imagine a 2D array that is 8x8, and each element has a value of either -1, 0, or 1. I want to continue running code only if both -1 and 1 are found within the array.

My problem is that I only know how to loop through the entire array such that I can get the value of the last element and test whether it would be -1 or 1, rather than testing if *any* of the array elements are 1 or -1.

I hope the code below illustrates what I am trying to do. Thanks.

```
for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        if(array[x][y] == 1)
        {
            stop checking
            oneExists = true;
        }
        if(array[x][y] == -1)
        {
            stop checking
            minusoneExists = true;
        }
        else
        {
            oneExists = false;
            minusoneExists = false;
        }
    }

    if(oneExists==true & minusoneExists==true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `break` statement to exit a `for` loop.

Comment: I thought of that, but if I put break in either of the first two if statements it only exits those and not the for loop, but if I put it in the first two for loops, they will exit on the first element. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: So I guess you need some kind of (bool) flag variable to indicate when both `for` loops must be exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
bool oneExists = false;
bool minusoneExists = false;
for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        if(array[x][y] == 1)
        {
            oneExists = true;
        }
        else if(array[x][y] == -1)
        {
            minusoneExists = true;
        }
        if(oneExists && minusoneExists) return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like below would probably do the trick:

```
oneExists = false;
minusoneExists = false;

for(int x=0; x<8 && ! (oneExists && minusoneExists); x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y<8  && ! (oneExists && minusoneExists); y++)
    {
        if(array[x][y] == 1)
        {
            oneExists = true;
        }
        if(array[x][y] == -1)
        {
            minusoneExists = true;
        }
    }
}

return oneExists && minusoneExists;
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but the problem is that if we imagine the first element is 1 then this will be the case: `oneExists=true & minusoneExists=false`. So far so good, but then move to the second element which if it is -1, now: `oneExists=false & minusoneExists=true`. I need in this case for `oneExists` to always equal `true` if it ever did in the loop and not revert back to `false`.

Comment: The two boolean flags are only set to false before the double-loop starts. So they will never be reverted back to false inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

how about this.

```
    for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
    {
        bool flag=true;
        for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
        {
            if(array[x][y]==0)
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!flag)
            return false;

    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard library:

```
bool contains(const int (&m)[8][8], int value)
{
    return std::any_of(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [value](const auto&a)
    {
        return std::any_of(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [value](int e)
        {
            return e == value;
        });
    });
}

bool contain_one_and_minus_one(const int (&m)[8][8])
{
    return contains(m, 1) && contains(m, -1);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/SvBcFI)